# Python Efficient conversion of time strings in multiple dimensions to datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-xarray

I want to convert the string date values inside a xarray DataArray to datetime index or python datetime object.
For example, lets take the DataArray

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
b = np.asarray(['2020-01-01T09:41:54.647000Z', '2020-01-01T09:41:55.487000Z',
       '2020-01-01T09:41:56.327000Z', '2020-01-01T09:41:57.167000Z',
       '2020-01-01T09:41:58.007000Z', '2020-01-01T09:41:58.847000Z',
       '2020-01-01T09:41:59.687000Z', '2020-01-01T09:42:00.527000Z',
       '2020-01-01T09:42:01.367000Z', '2020-01-01T09:42:02.207000Z',
       '2020-01-01T09:42:03.047000Z', '2020-01-01T09:42:03.887000Z'],
      dtype=object)
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars={'time_utc': (['x', 'y', 'z'], b.reshape((2,2,3)))},
       coords={'x': [0,1], 'y': [2,3], 'z':[0,1,2]})
```

In principle, I can convert a 1-D array using `pd.to_datetime()`
For example,

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(b)
```

But, my question is, how to I apply this function to xarray DataArray. I tried using `xr.apply_ufunc` as following

```
xr.apply_ufunc(pd.to_datetime, ds.time_utc)
```

but it throws an error

> TypeError: arg must be a string, datetime, list, tuple, 1-d array, or
> Series
> Most likely, pd.to_datetime is not vectorized and I can set

```
xr.apply_ufunc(pd.to_datetime, ds.time_utc, vectorize=True)
```

But then it is very slow (I have a large dataset). Is there some internal xarray utility for fast datetime conversion similar to that in Pandas?

Answer (score 1):

What you could try is flatten the time data, convert to datetime, then restore the original dimensions. EX:

```py
ds = xr.Dataset(data_vars={'time_utc': (['x', 'y', 'z'], b.reshape((2,2,3)))},
       coords={'x': [0,1], 'y': [2,3], 'z':[0,1,2]})
# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:   (x: 2, y: 2, z: 3)
# Coordinates:
#   * x         (x) int64 0 1
#   * y         (y) int64 2 3
#   * z         (z) int64 0 1 2
# Data variables:
#     time_utc  (x, y, z) object '2020-01-01T09:41:54.647000Z' ... '2020-01-01T...

t = ds["time_utc"].stack(alldims=("x", "y", "z"))

# xarray does not handle time zones, so remove it.
# 'format="ISO8601"' is a pandas 2.0 feature, remove it for older versions
t.values = pd.to_datetime(t, format="ISO8601").tz_localize(None)

ds["time_utc"] = t.unstack()
# <xarray.Dataset>
# Dimensions:   (x: 2, y: 2, z: 3)
# Coordinates:
#   * x         (x) int64 0 1
#   * y         (y) int64 2 3
#   * z         (z) int64 0 1 2
# Data variables:
#     time_utc  (x, y, z) datetime64[ns] 2020-01-01T09:41:54.647000 ... 2020-01...
``
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is indeed a faster way around. But can't we do the conversion without flattening?

Comment: @VinodKumar I'd assume string-to-datetime conversion is optimized for 1d-array, which essentially, in memory, any n-d array will map to. So I *guess* not. Btw. in your case, if using pandas 2+, you can add `format="ISO8601"` which could speed up things further.